# Need help adding date stamp to excel formula

Tags: arrays, excel, date, formula, datestamp

I have created an array formula I would like to add a current date timestamp mm/dd/yy to the end of it instead of changing the date manually as shown in the formula below. Is there any way I can fit that in to this formula?

Thanks for any help with this.

Here is the formula

=J2&" "&L2&" "&O2&" "&N2&" "&"Per OM nlh 2/4/15"

Comment: Basically a daily report is run and then my macro after that(different from the daily report from my previous question) and I needed the date to be the current day I ran the macro, as the formula above creates a comment that needs to have the day it was made at the end of the comment. I guess current date stamp might have been more accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your formula to this:

```
=J2&" "&L2&" "&O2&" "&N2&" "&"Per OM nlh "&TEXT(TODAY(),"m/d/yy")
```